# GNU Make4.1 Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, compiling, gnu-make

During a `make check` after compiling GNU Make-4.1, the following error occurs.

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/make-4.1'
cd tests && perl ./run_make_tests.pl -srcdir /mnt/lfs/sources/make-4.1 -make ../make 
sh: line 1:   705 Done                    echo "all:;@echo \$(MAKE)"
706 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | ../make -f-
FATAL ERROR: Cannot determine the value of $(MAKE):
```

`make install` will finish without error, but the application will still seg fault when initiated. The following error was take from `dmesg`.

```
segfault at 0 ip 00007f0eb0cca606 sp 00007fff2b27c1b8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f0eb0c4c000+198000]
```

Comment: That doesn't sound normal. Have you checked your hardware, particularly your memory?

Comment: You are trying to build LFS. Is this happening while compiling make in chapter 5 or chapter 6?

Comment: Chapter 5. Constructing a Temporary System

Comment: The test suites in Ch 5 are not meant to give meaningful results since most of them will fail anyways. The ones which are critical are clearly marked further on in the book. Make sure your host system requirements from the Preface are satisfied. I suggest you try compiling the next few tools in Ch 5 to see if it works. If so, you might be fine. You can also send a mail to the LFS support list if you want to dig deeper into this.

Comment: After installing `make` it's called from the tool chain from then on, as the path is explicitly set `PATH=/tools/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`. To continue compiling everything else in Chapter 5, I can call the host's `/usr/bin/make`, but I'm not sure this is how LFS is intended to be installed.

Comment: Do not use the host systems `make`. Also, please @ mention people on comments, otherwise it's hard to know when someone responds. Send a mail to lfssupport mail group. Someone there might be able to help. You'll have to register for that first at http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/listinfo/lfs-support/

Answer (score 0):

Recycling the environment would seem to be the culprit, which indicates to me that a specific environment setting/variable/configuration is not being retained in the event of a system halt. Provided I don't halt the host, I can compile the entire toolchain with the chain's `make` without errors.